# createResizablePolygon, createResizablePolyline, and createResizableRectangle All have errors

Tags: here-api

Both the polygon functions do not display the shapes because error is caught on reloading of the page.

Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: ~pj() (Argument #0 No image data)

Failure occurs on this line of code

```
polyline.getGeometry().eachLatLngAlt(function(lat, lng, alt, index)
```

The Rectangle function fails when you try to move the rectangle

Uncaught ReferenceError: currentGeoRect is not defined

The Code fails here

```
rectGroup.addEventListener('drag', function(evt) {
     var pointer = evt.currentPointer,
         pointerGeoPoint = map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY);
         currentGeoRect = rect.getGeometry().getBoundingBox(),
         objectTopLeftScreen = map.geoToScreen(currentGeoRect.getTopLeft()),
         objectBottomRightScreen = map.geoToScreen(currentGeoRect.getBottomRight());
```

I am only taking the examples from here https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/resizable-geoshapes/resizable-polygon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for finding this.
It is an issue in the tool which is responsible for generating the documentation. 
the value of js variable `svgCircle` is not displayed properly and that is causing your issue:
[image: code screenshot]

Will be fixed soon.

As a workaround, please open related [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/resizable-polygon) + hit `Run` button. The code is shown properly there:

```
var svgCircle = '<svg width="20" height="20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
      '<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" fill="transparent" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"/>' +
      '</svg>'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Tomas!

Comment: What about the Resizable Rectangle? that one has a different issue I took the code from Jfiddle as well